# highchart background with three colorfull

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I can create just one part of this Chart background! i need your help ....

```
       var chartOptions = {
        type: 'scatter',
        backgroundColor: {
            linearGradient: {
                x1: 0,
                y1: 0,
                x2: 1,
                y2: 0.7
            },
            stops: [
                [0, '#8F9DB9'], 
                [0, '#AADBED']
            ]
        },
    }
```

at the end of my sample is

```
var xAxis = chart.xAxis[0];
chartOptions.backgroundColor.stops[0][0] = 0.45
```

what does above line ?

Comment: Please explain your code, if you can create a sample working example. it will be helpful to understand the question.

Comment: Could you be more precise and prepare a working demo in an online code editor like jsfiddle?